# how to assign color for span element dynamically in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css

I want to assign the color of the span element dynamically. The json which is returned from the web service has a mapping to status and color and looks like this:

```
status: {
active: "#ffff00",
any_other: "#ff0000",
}
```

Now in my html I want to check the status of each employee and then assign a color to the span element.I am returning the color from the controller but the UI does not update it. The following is my code:

```
<div  ng-repeat="emp in employees" ng-init='xcoordinate=getTransformedXValues(emp); ycoordinate=getTransformedYValues(emp); toolColor = getempStatusColor(emp);'>
<span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-oil" id="{{emp.empId}}" 
       ng-style="{'cursor': 'pointer','color':toolColor,'position': 'absolute',
      'left': xValue + xcoordinate, 'top': yValue - ycoordinate, 'z-index': '2'}"/>

</div>
```

Could you let me know what I am missing here. I am thinking that the way I am assigning the color value to the color attribute is wrong.

Comment: If u ou just put {{statusColor}} before your span, does it output the value you are expecting? It looks like you are putting it in a variable called toolColor, not statusColor. Btw-You should probably create your own directive for this and then do all the logic to figure out that style object in there.

Comment: @mcgraphix When I output before the span element it does not show the value and just prints toolColor. Sorry I made a typing mistake in the above code, both the places I have toolColor only.

Comment: Are you sure getempStatusColor () is returning the correct value?

Comment: Yes I printed the value in console.log to see what is the value being returned.

Comment: Create a working snippet, fiddle or plunkr and it would be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: How about other values like `xcoordinate`? Can you get it correctly?

Comment: @Sky Yes I am able to get the other values. It is only with the color value.

Comment: Try to remove the whitespace to see if it works.